# php cookies changes not being picked up in the same domain

Tags: php, html, cookies

I have a UI page the collects various values and saves them to a database.
Some of these values I store as cookies in the back end create/update scripts and these are set to expire after 24 hours.

An example of this is:

```
    if (isset($_POST["clone_on_sale"])) {
        setcookie("mi_clone_on_sale", "Y", time() + $expiryTime);
    } else {
        setcookie("mi_clone_on_sale", "N", time() + $expiryTime);
    }
```

When I change this clone_on_sale value in the UI and save it, the backend scripts always displays the same values in the $_COOKIE variable even though I've checked and it is hitting the correctly logic block and setting them to Y or N respectively.

In the UI page it picks up these cookies as well to use them in the display using the following code:

```
$cookieCloneOnSale = "N";
if (isset($_COOKIE["mi_clone_on_sale"])) {
 $cookieCloneOnSale = $_COOKIE["mi_clone_on_sale"];
}
```

Within the PHP code the $_COOKIES are not being updated:

```
array (
'mi_category' => '1',
'mi_auto_relist' => 'Y',
'mi_clone_on_sale' => 'Y', //<<always Y
'mi_refunds_allowed' => 'Y',
'mi_pct_for_charity' => '20',
'mi_price' => '12.00',
'mi_min_price' => '12.00'
)
```

But when i check the domain cookies in chrome I can see these cookies are actually getting updated correctly each time. (Notice clone_on_sale below)

[image]

I'm not sure if there's a step i'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setcookie()` does not affects `$_COOKIE` array immediately because it just sets header with cookie data for current request. They will be picked up right on next request by your scripts. During current request `$_COOKIE` will stay in the same state.

I suggest you to store all updated data in different class or array. The simplest solution will be setting a different array along with setting cookie:

```
$cookieData = []
if (isset($_POST["clone_on_sale"])) {
    setcookie("mi_clone_on_sale", "Y", time() + $expiryTime);
    $cookieData['mi_clone_on_sale'] = 'Y';
} else {
    setcookie("mi_clone_on_sale", "N", time() + $expiryTime);
    $cookieData['mi_clone_on_sale'] = 'N';
}
```

Or you can use a batter approach and create a class with `getCookie` and `setCookie` methods.

Also, you don't setting your cookies for the whole domain, you can do it by providing an `/` as the fourth parameter to `setcookie`:

```
 setcookie("mi_clone_on_sale", "N", time() + $expiryTime, '/');
```

In case you don't set it, your cookie will work only for current directory in subdirectories where the script is located.